# Android ListView shifts down after display to show first item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListActivity with a single ListView in its layout. When first displayed everything is OK, all text items are immediately visible. However, on subsequent displays (originating from other Activities), the list displays starting from 2nd item, then redraws itself from 1st. The end result is correct, but what is annoying is the unnecessary list movement (the whole list shifts down to show its 1st item). Tried many things and googled around, without success.

Comment: We need to see your code otherwise we have to respond without success

Comment: I had hoped that maybe someone has already seen a similar pattern w/o going into too much detail. I wonder if I can reproduce the issue on a smaller example.

Comment: I don't think anybody can help much without seeing your code. Wait and see

Answer (score 0):

Register for the onPreDraw listener on the list view. In the onPreDraw function callback, check if the the

```
listView.firstVisiblePosition() == 0
```

if it is then return true.
If its not then do

```
listView.setSelection(0)
```

and return false, so that the listview draws itself again. This time with the first item selected.